# Will clothing effect a baby's S.P.E.C.I.A.L.?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I've been playing Fallout Shelter for 2 days now and was wondering if the clothing on dwellers affect the baby's S.P.E.C.I.A.L. For instance if both of the parents have average S.P.E.C.I.A.L. (like everything is 1 or 2) but when I put a certain clothing (for example) intelligence and  perception goes up. Will the baby have a higher chance of having one or both of those stats higher?

Comment: Please don't add the game name to the title as we can clearly see what game it is through the tag.

Comment: Ok I just really need an answer, my vault is progressing faster than I thought.

Comment: Actually game title in the question title is completely fine. This was discussed a while back. Its also fine to edit the name out of the title, providing it is not all you do. For the user that undid the edit on SPECIAL, SPECIAL is an acronym. As such, it is properly displayed with full stops after each letter.

Comment: This is also how it is usually displayed ingame

Comment: No, there's no standard for how SPECIAL is spelled. For example, in the in-game help file, it's spelled SPECIAL. You're spelling it SPECIAL in these comments. Most importantly, acronyms aren't typically spelled with periods in them these days. No one writes L.A.S.E.R. or A.T.&T.

Answer (score 3):

Based on some testing in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3jdiao/special_inheritance_and_super_children_vaulttec/), the stat increases from clothing do not seem to affect the inheritance.

Answer (score -2):

I am late on this topic but figured I'd add some more context. As being already answered in short, no clothing doesn't affect a baby's stats. Only the actual stats from parents will be passed on to the offspring.

In addition, it seems to be a random pick between fathers or mothers max stat that is inherited. I have been playing for quite some time now and 1 out of 10 babies have inherited the fathers max stat in my playthrough in which I do not intertwine relations (same mother/father for all kids in specific family).

Keep in mind this is 2022 updated client.